# Java mqtt client SSL config with self signed certificate

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, mqtt, paho

This is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("ssl://127.0.0.1:8883", "randomId");
client.setCallback(new MyCallback());
MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
options.setConnectionTimeout(60);
options.setKeepAliveInterval(60);
//Something like this
//options.setSSLProperties(sslProperties());
client.connect(options);
client.subscribe("topic", 0);
```

```
    private Properties sslProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(SSLSocketFactoryFactory.CA, "/home/ca.crt");
    }
```

I'm using a tool called MQTTfx. I only have to point to my ca.crt file and it connects to my mosquitto broker. How would I be able to specify my certificate file in Java?

This is what my mosquitto config looks like:

```
port 8883

cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not that simple.
You are going to need to create an instance of a `SSLSocketFactory` that has a custom `TrustStore` that points to your CA certificate. You then pass this `SSLSocketFactory` to the `MqttClient` as an option in `MqttConnectOptions`.

Something a little like (this has no exception handling, will need wrapping in appropriate try/catch block)

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
trustStore.load(null,null);
trustStore.setCertificateEntry("Custom CA", (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509").generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("/home/ca.crt")));

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(trustStore);
TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory =  sslContext.getSocketFactory();

//where options is the MqttConnectOptions object
options.setSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the reply! Unfortunately I get the following error:

`Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present.`

`MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names present`

And this is the info I get on my mosquitto broker:

`OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown`

Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.

Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: That implies your server cert doesn't have a CN or SAN entry that matches the name of the server you used to connect (`127.0.0.1`) . This is different problem than trusting your CA. Using certs with IP addresses is normally a bad idea as it just adds complications.

Comment: I created my cert with "localhost". I now switched my connection in code to localhost instead of using the ip address and I get `no name matching localhost found`. Still the same problem I suppose. I really don't know what's causing the issue.

Comment: As I've  said, this is a different problem (so new question with a LOT more detail about what you did). p.s. deleting and reposting the same comment again to trigger a notification is rude and makes me want to not help any more.

Comment: I made some modifications to my comment and as I couldn't find the option to edit, I reposted it. Sorry for the double notification. I'll try to play around with the config a little bit and see what comes out. Thank you for your time and insights!

Comment: I did some tests and I still think it's an issue with how I set up my certificate in Java. I checked the certificate and the CN is set to `127.0.0.1`. In my code I also use this ip address to connect to the client. This works: `mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -p 8883 -t /topic/# --cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt` so my certificate looks to be valid. And I can also connect using the tool MQTTfx. I was thinking that maybe I had to add the port to the CN but that isn't the case.

Comment: Hi @hardillb I am having a Azure event grid MQTT, on web socket it supports authentication using client certificates and client key. I used the [this](https://gist.github.com/jimrok/d25cb45b840f5a4ad700) code to create socket factory but I am getting ` javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty` exception while connecting to the broker. While I check with other MQTT client like MQTTBox and MQTTX then connection is successful . How can show some light on what wrong I am doing here?